# How do I find a value anywhere in a SQL Server Database using c#.net?

Tags: c#

How do I find a value anywhere in a SQL Server Database using c#.net?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Are you asking how to see if a given value exists in any column of any row of any table, view or table function in a given database.  If you are this would be complex, and you need to specify what you want to be returned.

Answer (score 5):

Roughly put, you would first have to query the database scheme in order to get all tables:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Then, navigate through the resultset, using the returned table names in a new query

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = [resulting table name from previous query]
```

From here you can cycle each column and create a select statement using a column value with
    where = '[searchterm]'.

Answer (score 1):

Read this simple tutorials on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx) and on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C). There are alot of examples and tutorial on internet. Just google it